# Adding an integer property to server side control dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my user control

`<site:videoAxis ID="player" PlayerType="BlogPage"  Width="620" Height="348" runat="server"/>` I want to add a control DefaultVid dynamically.

what is the best way to add it?

Right now, I have it like this

```
    <% if (ClipId > 0)
            { player.DefaultVid = ClipId;%>
        <site:videoAxis ID="player" PlayerType="BlogPage"  Width="620" Height="348" runat="server"/>

        <%
            } %>
```

It works correctly now. But I don't think that is the best way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the technique you posted is a good way to do this, and is likely what I would have done. There is nothing wrong with it, and, based on its simplicity, alternative preferences would likely just be matters of opinion.